# why isnt my addClass() function isnt working?

Tags: javascript

I would like to add a class to my `<select>` so I am using this function which is in the main.js file, everything is linked but it doesnt seem to be working and I dont know why

```
function addClass(){
    var element = document.getElementById("qtranxs_select_qtranslate-chooser");
element.classList.add("select language-select");
};
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: classList.add needs a comma seperated list for mutiple classes: `element.classList.add("select", "language-select");`

Comment: @theblackgigant Note: multiple arguments will not work in IE